# wso2 governance registry - client looks up service and call service

Tags: api, service, registry, wso2

I understand that a web service client may use the governance registry to return an endpoint of a service that implements the wsdl specified by the client.

The client can then use the endpoint to call the service.

The benefit of this approach using the governance registry is that the client does not need to know the location of the destination service up front.  The client only needs to know the wsdl and the location of the registry service.  Is this a valid reason for using the governance registry?

Is there any sample code that demonstrates the use case I have described above?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes that would be an valid reason to use the governance registry and what you have mentioned can be done using the WSO2 GREG. take a look at the following sample i think it should help you[1]

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance452/Endpoint+Look-up+Sample